# Flask redirect post login does not redirect

Tags: python, flask

As seen in the code below, the flask function for login does not return but instead stays on the login page, when i believe it should be redirected to the user page.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session.permanent = True
        fname_ = request.form["fname_"]
        password = request.form["password_"]
        print(f"login in detailes aqquired: FIRSTNAME:{user}, PWD:{password}")
        found_user = session.query(Person).filter_by(firstname=fname_).first()
        if found_user:
            session["fname_"] = found_user.firstname
            return redirect(url_for("user", usr=fname_))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("login.html")
```

The database is set up as so:

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "people"

    firstname = Column("firstname", String, primary_key=True)
    lastname = Column("lastname", String)
    age = Column("age", Integer)
    password = Column("password", String)

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, password):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.password = password

Engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.db", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=Engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=Engine)
```

Im attempting to check if the user form parameter exists in the database, and then redirect to the user page however i am having troubles with the redirect, im also not sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: Why are you not using `flask-login`?

Comment: its more of the act of calling the database and displaying the data, im still unsure why it is happening

Comment: This would happen if the query filed to find a `Person`. Are you extra sure that you have data in `/mydb.db` the corresponds to the query?

Comment: yeah, i went so far as opening the db in sqllite to double check